# Check-in like data modeling / 3 way relationships

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

Having a bit of a blank when laying out some database designs.

Say if I have the below relationships.

- A user belongs to many games and a game can have many users
- A session has many sessions and a session belongs to one game

I want to model a sort of RSVP or check in system for all users belonging to a game to mark themselves as attending a session. 
First idea was a list in session, but usually if that's my solution I'm doing something wrong in relational databases.

[image]

Is the answer a many to many relationship between session and user? This seems to not capture how games comes into the relationship however.

Am I missing something very obvious here? How would you model this relationship? (if it even needs to be)

Answer (score 1):

For displaying a list of all sessions for a specific user you would obtain the collection of sessions by a join query via `games` that fetches all sessions of all games of a user.

If running this query would take too much time, you would have to extend your design by adding an explicit many-to-many association between `users` and `sessions`, which should be derived (as a materialized view) from the association path `users`-`games`-`sessions`.